# How to take print out of web page on A4 paper size

Tags: cakephp

I have to take print out of web page on A4 paper size. and i wont an image background as bottom mark on center of tha page which css property should i use  to achieve this . I tried background property what don't know how to center the image..

Comment: Do u want to take print out of webpage? ctrl+p

Answer (score 0):

If you want the background image to be on every page then you will have to fix your background image via css property and use ctrl+p to get A4 print it(image) will be printed on every page as bottom mark. Image property can be set as

```
<style>
body 
{
background-image:url('w3css.gif');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-attachment:fixed;
background-position:center; 
}
</style>
```

if you want to test this property you can test it

Click [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_background-attachment)!